# child div extend beyond parent div styled with overflow

Tags: html, css, user-interface, position

I am using a select control that is created with several nested divs and hidden input.  I need this wrapper div, set to absolute positioning to not take up vertical height of the parent, but be in a layer over the parent div should there be a scroll in said parent.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/sammarcow/pen/LQWZKL)

```
<style>
.contentOverflow {
      width: 450px;
      height: 80px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      overflow: auto;
    }

#select_wrapper{
  position:relative;
}

#divselect {
  margin-top:60px;
  background-color:lightblue;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  overflow:visible;
}
</style>

<div> class="contentOverflow">   
  <div id="select_wrapper">
    <div id="divselect" >
      This should display beyond .contentoverflow but must be a child of the .contentoverflow div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give value auto to in which child div is more than parent div. For example:   If parent div is less height than child then `<div style="height:auto"><div>blah blah</div></div>` . So it will adjust height according to the child.

Comment: Please do not work around the codepen link. You should allways paste your code or add a snippet if you want to give a codepen link.

Comment: I cannot set the height to auto, I want scrolling to occur on the parent div and for a max-height to restrict the height of its content.  Editable list data is shown within a scrollable div, and we need any child divs styled as ComboBox to appear as if out of box Select controls, which would scroll past the parent container.